# Resources Text File Found During Unit Test But Not When Program Run From Netbeans

Tags: java, javafx

[My project files are like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imwYO.png)

[My files are like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arB6e.png)

Unit Test output is this,

```
readNameDataFile
test reading text file...
User directory: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Traveller
Current directory: .
File path + name: names/names.txt
ClassLoader :file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Traveller/build/classes/names/names.txt
test first NameData object is correct...
test fifth NameData object is correct...
test last NameData object is correct...
```

Stacktrace is this,

```
Executing C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Traveller\dist\run667857124\Traveller.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre/bin/java
Database starting in embedded mode.
Connected to database TravellerDB
User directory: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Traveller
Current directory: .
File path + name: names/names.txt
ClassLoader : jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Traveller/dist/run667857124/Traveller.jar!/names/names.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Traveller\dist\run667857124\Traveller.jar!\names\names.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
Shutting TravellerDB database down...
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.io.FileReader.readNameDataFile(FileReader.java:35)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.names.GeneratorModel.initNameMaps(GeneratorModel.java:85)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.names.GeneratorModel.<init>(GeneratorModel.java:31)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.names.GeneratorController.initialize(GeneratorController.java:65)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1143)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.Main.start(Main.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in Application start method
Derby shut down normally.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Traveller/dist/run667857124/Traveller.jar!/io/github/drw/traveller/names/GeneratorView.fxml
file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Traveller/dist/run667857124/Traveller.jar!/io/github/drw/traveller/Main.fxml:38

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1143)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.Main.start(Main.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.github.drw.traveller.io.FileReader.readNameDataFile(FileReader.java:44)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.names.GeneratorModel.initNameMaps(GeneratorModel.java:85)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.names.GeneratorModel.<init>(GeneratorModel.java:31)
    at io.github.drw.traveller.names.GeneratorController.initialize(GeneratorController.java:65)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application io.github.drw.traveller.Main
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Traveller\dist\run667857124
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Can someone clarify why my FileReader class finds the text file when running from the unit test but not when the program is run as an application using Netbeans->Run?

FileReader

```
package io.github.drw.traveller.io;

import io.github.drw.traveller.names.Gender;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Reads data in from files.
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class FileReader {

private final String path;
private final String fileName;

public FileReader(String path, String fileName) {
    this.path = path;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public List<NameData> readNameDataFile() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("User directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.out.println("Current directory: " + new File("."));
    System.out.println("File path + name: " + path + "/" + fileName);
    System.out.println("ClassLoader : " + classLoader.getResource(path + "/" + fileName));
    Scanner scanner = null;
    final List<NameData> names = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(path + "/" + fileName).getFile());
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] items = line.split(" ");
            names.add(processItems(items));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
    return names;
}

private NameData processItems(String[] items) {
    Gender gender;
    String item;
    item = items[0];
    if (item.equals("MF")) {
        gender = Gender.BOTH;
    } else if (item.equals("MO")) {
        gender = Gender.MALE;
    } else {
        gender = Gender.FEMALE;
    }
    boolean canBeLastName;
    item = items[1];
    if (item.equals("LY")) {
        canBeLastName = true;
    } else {
        canBeLastName = false;
    }
    String value = items[2].toLowerCase();
    char[] characters = value.toCharArray();
    characters[0] = Character.toUpperCase(characters[0]);
    value = String.copyValueOf(characters);
    return new NameData(value, gender, canBeLastName);
}

}
```

FileReaderTest

```
package io.github.drw.traveller.io;

import io.github.drw.traveller.names.Gender;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Tests the FileReader functionality.
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class FileReaderTest {

public FileReaderTest() {
}

/**
 * Test of readNameDataFile method, of class FileReader.
 */
@Test
public void testReadNameDataFile() {
    System.out.println("readNameDataFile");
    System.out.println("test reading text file...");
    FileReader instance = new FileReader("names", "names.txt");
    List<NameData> list = instance.readNameDataFile();
    int expectedSize = 5163;
    int actualSize = list.size();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedSize, actualSize);
    System.out.println("test first NameData object is correct...");
    NameData actual, expected;
    expected = new NameData("Aaron", Gender.BOTH, true);
    actual = list.get(0);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    System.out.println("test fifth NameData object is correct...");
    expected = new NameData("Abdul", Gender.MALE, true);
    actual = list.get(4);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    System.out.println("test last NameData object is correct...");
    expected = new NameData("Zulma", Gender.FEMALE, false);
    actual = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

}
```

Sorry about the links but I'm new to SO and I can't upload images yet.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode: Type out your stacktrace and code at the very least. This will allow us to easily search for the error to provide assistance.

Comment: Please post your code and error message here directly instead of an image.

Comment: Have edited question as requested :-)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I'm glad to see that you've managed to find an answer to your own question. When that happens here instead of editing the answer into the question itself, we encourage users to submit an answer to their own question and then mark that answer as accepted. This also eliminates the need to change the title to "Solved" or "Fixed" or whatever, since the question will be shown shown with a solid green box indicating its resolved status.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for letting me know. I'll make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I changed the FileReader.readNameDataFile() method to this,

```
public List<NameData> readNameDataFile() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("User directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.out.println("Current directory: " + new File("."));
    System.out.println("File path + name: " + path + "/" + fileName);
    System.out.println("ClassLoader : " + classLoader.getResource(path + "/" + fileName));
    final List<NameData> names = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path + "/" + fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] items = line.split(" ");
                names.add(processItems(items));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.